# Getting a class bytcode on android

Tags: android, bytecode, dalvik, android-package-managers, bytecode-manipulation

I want to send on the wire a class file (.class) for execution on a remote server. I can not use serialization, because the class does not exist on server side, and I want to add new classes dynamically. I don't want to use RMI.

On Dekstop Java, it's easy to do with:

- Loading the class with `Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("mypackage.MyClass")`.
- Getting access to the file (or jar container) with `URL url = clazz.getResource("MyClass.class")`

On Android, I succeeded loading a class instance with this [hack](http://www.bravenewgeek.com/implementing-spring-like-classpath-scanning-in-android/) but`clazz.getResource()` always returns null.
(And this is logical as Dalvik storage format is different).

I have tried Apache BCEL, but it does not work. Following code throws a `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
 JavaClass clazz = Repository .lookupClass("mypackage.mMyClass");
 byte[] b = clazz.getBytes();
```

Is there a way to translate a Dalvik byte code to regular class byte code on Android so that I can rebuild a .class file from it and then send it on the wire?

Thanks.

Comment: It would probably be simpler to hack a build system which copies certain classes in intermediate java bytecode form to the Android resources system, so that you can read them from there at runtime.

Comment: @Chris Stratton, yes this is the best and - maybe - only solution. I wanted to avoid it because it requires a small procedure for the users of my software. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't use `.class` files. It uses `.dex` files, which is a completely different format. Tools such as `dx` and `dex2jar` can translate back and forth most of the time, but it's not perfect because each format has different features that don't quite map into the other.

Anyway, I think the easiest thing to do would be to compile it on the desktop and bundle all the `.class` files as resources in your apk. The actual code executed will still be `classes.dex` but that way you can retrieve the stored class files and send them to your server.

Incidentally, sending arbitrary classfiles to a server for execution sounds like a very, very, bad idea. Please don't do this on any computer you care about.